# Adding multiple email addresses to php email form

Tags: php, forms, dreamweaver

I created a php email form for a contact us page to my site, and want to use the same form for multiple email addresses. However, when I copy the code to the new page and add a different email address, it goes to the same email address as the original contact form.

I change the

```
$email_to = 'example@gmail.com, customer@website.com';
```

to a different email address, but it won't work, and keeps sending to the original email address.

How can I make this form usable for multiple emails for multiple email forms?

```
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'SARAI.ROMEROEVANS@lausd.net, customer@website.com';
$email_subject = 'Contact Form Submission Bancroft Website';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
    'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>
```

If you need more code, let me know

Comment: it's on the website http://bancroftmiddleschool.org under the "contact us" heading in the navigation bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't specify multiple email addresses in the first parameter of the mail() function. EDIT - you can, but I had assumed this wasn't possible as it has caused my problems in the past.

Here is an edited version of your code. I split $email_to up by commas and then loop through each email address to send an email to each.

I have also added some if statements to control who the recipients are. If you are going to re-use the code for multiple forms then pass a `formID` as a hidden field and then you can specify in the PHP who should receive the emails. No need to duplicate the PHP code for each form then ...

```
<?php

// Set email variables

if($_POST['formID'] == 1) {
    $email_to = 'SARAI.ROMEROEVANS@lausd.net, customer@website.com';
} elseif($_POST['formID'] == 2) {
    $email_to = 'test@test.com, customer@website.com';
} else {
    $email_to = 'blah@blah.com, customer@website.com';  
}

$email_subject = 'Contact Form Submission Bancroft Website';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
    'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email

        $email = explode(',', $email_to);

        foreach($email as $e) {
            $e = trim($e);
            mail($e, $email_subject, $email_content);
        }        

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>
```

Comment: According to the documentation for `mail()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), you can have multiple email addresses in the first parameter.

Comment: I would add this, then copy and paste the whole thing into the new form? Would I add the new address into the $email = explode(',', $email_to); line?

Comment: Let me check, so you want to have multiple contact forms on different pages on your site. Different forms need to be sent to different sets of recipients. At the moment the form is only being sent to the first email address in your list, the one after the comma isn't receiving the email?

Comment: Yes, i want multiple forms with on different pages for different email addresses. When I create a new form, and change the email address in the $email_to = 'example@gmail.com, customer@website.com'; line, it email sends to the original address

Comment: What happens is when i change $email_to = 'example@gmail.com, customer@website.com'; to       $email_to = 'example2222@gmail.com, customer@website.com'; in a new form, it would send to example@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you. How do I specify the form id's on a new html page with a new form?